# Matter waves require a medium for propagation

Tags: waves, vacuum, matter

I have read:

> 1. Matter waves require a medium to for propagation.
> 2. Matter waves do not leave the moving particle, i.e. are not emitted.

But when a particle is moving with some velocity in vacuum, what happens to the matter wave? Matter wave can neither leave the particle nor can they move in vacuum. Where is my interpretation of matter waves wrong?

Comment: It's hard to answer this because you have the wrong idea about what [matter waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) are. A matter wave is just the momentum eigenstate of a particle i.e. a matter wave is just a particle in a particular type of quantum state.

Comment: @JohnRennie so when we say that a particle is travelling in vacuum what is the medium for the propagation of the matter wave?

Comment: @JohnRennie can you also suggest a video or some source for a better interpretation of matter waves

Comment: The matter wave is a wavefunction that describes the particle. Actually I wouldn't use the term *matter wave* as I think it's obsolete. A propagating particle is described by a wavefunction and you can calculate things like the energy and momentum from the wavefunction. So I think you should forget about matter waves and learn about wavefunctions.

Comment: @JohnRennie so what does the propagation of this function even mean? How does it require a medium for propagation?

Comment: The main site shouldn't be used for this sort of discussion, but I'd be happy to discuss this in the chat room. [Click here to join the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest answer would be to say that #1 is wrong.  Where did you hear that matter waves required a medium to propagate?  Since I agree that what you mean by "matter wave" sounds like a wavefunction, those don't require a medium.   One might even say this was the biggest surprise in the history of physics-- we find a form of wavelike behavior without a medium.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of thinking about this issue is badly muddled. Quantum mechanics describes systems in terms of wave functions. A wave function is not a particle. Rather, you can measure various properties of the wave function like momentum or charge or whatever. The states that can be detected by such interactions are constrained in some ways. For example, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle limits the extent to which you can narrow the spread of the wave function in position and momentum. If the wave function has a small uncertainty in position, the uncertainty in momentum has to be higher. A wave function can still have position and momentum spread that is too narrow for you to notice in everyday life, but that spread will be there.

Particles don't exist independently of the wave function and so there is simply no question at all of the wave function leaving the particle. The particle is just a particular kind of mode of the wave function. There is also no independent medium in which the wave function moves. It's just a kind of physical system that exists and obeys a set of physical laws, such as the Schrodinger equation.